# I used to store float in a variable for single use but I can't seem to store float in an array

Tags: javascript, store

Storing float number in an array is working just fine but when I store them in an array, the console says that the float number I stored in an array is `NaN` (not a number). I tried parsing it but that doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: What code are you running that is giving you this issue?

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce [the issue] in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Answer (score 0):

use  Float64Arrays and it  can't grow and shrink like ordinary Javascript  arrays. You have to allocate all the elements while  creating it=>

```
var sym = new Float64Array(5);


sym[0] = 343.46;
console.log(sym);
> [343.46, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: sir forgive me for this question of mine but. i just want to confirm if i understand it well (since i'm new to JS) , so float64Array would allow me to store float right? since the float i'm about to store is from a map API that would expand to 14.12357136114 something like this

Comment: Float32Array 1.2x10-38 to 3.4x1038 4 32-bit IEEE floating point number ( 7 significant digits e.g. 1.1234567) unrestricted float float
Float64Array 5.0x10-324 to 1.8x10308 8 64-bit IEEE floating point number (16 significant digits e.g. 1.123...15) unrestricted double double

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays read the follow link  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array read this two link

Comment: follow up result on float64, i stored it successfully but when i'm about to retrieve the data it just returns 0 instead, any idea sir?